# How to select inner join where count is GT?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I would like to select my items where exist more than zero keywords.

My current slq is:

```
SELECT `item`.`subject` AS `item_subject`
FROM   `item` `item`
       INNER JOIN `keyword_items_item` `keywords_item`
               ON `keywords_item`.`itemid` = `item`.`id`
       INNER JOIN `keyword` `keywords`
               ON `keywords`.`id` = `keywords_item`.`keywordid`
WHERE  Count(`keywords`.`id`) > 0
```

But looks like that where is wrong.

Can you help me to solve this problem?Thank you.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Given the use of `count()` where is the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`?

Answer (score 1):

Try below Query:

```
SELECT `item`.`subject` AS `item_subject`
FROM   `item` `item`
       INNER JOIN `keyword_items_item` `keywords_item`
               ON `keywords_item`.`itemid` = `item`.`id`
       INNER JOIN `keyword` `keywords`
               ON `keywords`.`id` = `keywords_item`.`keywordid`
GROUP BY `keywords`.`id`, `item`.`subject`
HAVING  Count(`keywords`.`id`) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The joins are enough to return only the subjects that have at least 1 keyword.
Just add `DISTINCT` after `SELECT` in case you get duplicate results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.subject AS item_subject
FROM item i
INNER JOIN keyword_items_item kit ON kit.itemid = i.id
INNER JOIN keyword k ON k.id = kit.keywordid
```